# Find number deleted from array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am quite new to ruby so bear with me, I have two arrays and we are meant to find the number which is missing.

The starting array sequence is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
The mixed array with one deleted number is 5 [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]

My idea is to add up each array and see which number is missing- I started to produce a method (I know it is shabby but I am learning)

```
def find_deleted_number(arr, mixed)
  arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  mixed = [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]
  y = arr.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
  x = mixed_arr.inject(0){|total, y| total + y}
  return y - x
end
```

Could anyone guide me to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: Just a short side node: You should really use the array#sum method instead of the inject :+ approach. This is because the sum method is way fast than the inject style. The reason is, that the sum method uses a math formular to calculate the sum and has therefore not so much to calculate.[link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum)

Comment: You can just do `arr.inject(:+)` and `mixed.inject(:+)` instead

Comment: @VamsiKrishna or for Ruby > 2.4.0 `arr.sum` etc

Comment: Could the two arrays be ` [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9]` and `[3,3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]`? If "yes", you will need to first apply the method [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to both arrays. In future, consider waiting longer to select an answer. A quick selection may discourage other answers and imo is inconsiderate to those still working on answers. There is no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in `mixed` as an argument and then are using it as `mixed_arr.inject...`, seems to work fine making those consistent.

Also, since you are passing in the `arr` and `mixed` you don't need them to be set in the method, you can call it as

```
find_deleted_number([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9])
```

and then remove

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
mixed = [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]
```

from the beginning of your method.

Comment: And I thought I was way far off! Thanks.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there are more succinct or idiomatic ways to perform the function of "finding the difference between 2 arrays" or even just doing the `inject`, but Imo, this wasn't really a "optimize my algorithm" or "how do I do this" question but a "What's wrong with this code", which is why I pointed out the typo; though it is useful to learn the other things in other answers and comments as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use *Array Difference*

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] - [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]
 #=> [5]
```

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D):

> **ary - other_ary → new_ary**
>
> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in other_ary. The order is preserved from the
>   original array.
>
> It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency

Comment: How can ruby know to subtract them all if we are not explicitly telling them to add the integers up before doing so?

Comment: This will work for numbers. For arrays ruby has overwritten the "-" operator. see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D)

Comment: @Benjamints That is not what Ruby does . What do you expect  to be the result of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] + [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]` ?  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] - [3,2,4,6,7,8,1,9]` does the opposite.

Comment: Technically, it's not subtraction. It's set difference.

Comment: `Array#-` is perfect for this problem. Not only is it short, clean and essentially self-documenting, but it works when either or both arrays contain duplicates.